# Symfony 3: Login not working

Tags: php, symfony

I got a login form that submit in post but don't seems to autenticate, i can see Anonymous in profiler even if i login as admin.

I'm taking data from Database:

```
| ID | username | password | email  | active |
| 1  |  admin   |  admin   | a@dm.in|   1    |
```

Naturally the password stored in database is encrypted.

**security.yml** (app/config/security.yml)

```
security:
    providers:
        db_provider:
             entity:
                  class: AppBundle:User
                  manager_name: customer
                  property:  username

    firewalls:
        login_firewall:
            pattern:   ^/login$
            anonymous: ~
            provider: db_provider
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            provider: db_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                username_parameter: _username
                password_parameter: _password

    access_control:
            - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
            - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
            - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    encoders:
            AppBundle\Entity\User:
                algorithm: bcrypt
```

**SecurityController.php** (src/AppBundle/Controller)

```
    <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: andreaem
 * Date: 17/09/16
 * Time: 18:43
 */

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render(
            'security/login.html.twig',
            array(
                // last username entered by the user
                'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                'error'         => $error,
            )
        );
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/login_check", name="security_login_check")
     */
    public function loginCheckAction()
    {
        // will never be executed
    }
}
```

**User.php** (src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php)

```
    <?php

    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

    /**
    * @ORM\Table(name="app_users")
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
    */
    class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
    {
        /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
        * @ORM\Id
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
        */
        private $id;

        /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
        */
        private $username;

        /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
        */
        private $password;

        /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
        */
        private $email;

        /**
        * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
        */
        private $isActive;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->isActive = true;
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
        }

        public function getUsername()
        {
            return $this->username;
        }

        public function getSalt()
        {
        // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
        // see section on salt below
            return null;
        }

        public function getPassword()
        {
            return $this->password;
        }

        public function getRoles()
        {
            return array('ROLE_USER');
        }

        public function eraseCredentials()
        {
        }

        /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
        public function serialize()
        {
            return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
                $this->isActive,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
            ));
        }

        /** @see \Serializable::unserialize()
         * @param string $serialized
         */
        public function unserialize($serialized)
        {
            list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
                $this->isActive,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
        }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }
}
```

**UserRepository** (src/AppBundle/Entity/UserRepository.php)

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;

/**
 * UserRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.username = :username OR u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('username', $username)
            ->setParameter('email', $username)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

**login.html.twig** (app/Resources/views/security/login.html.twig)

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}


<div class="darker-stripe">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ path('homepage') }}">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="icon-chevron-right"></span></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ path('login') }}">Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="container">
    <div class="push-up top-equal blocks-spacer">
        <div class="row blocks-spacer">
            <div class="span4"></div>
            <div class="span4">
                {% if error %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger in fade">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                        {{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
                <br>
                <h1 class="title text-center">
                    Login
                </h1>
                <br><br>
            <form method="post" action="{{ path('login') }}">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label hidden shown-ie8" for="inputEmail">Username</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" placeholder="Username" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label hidden shown-ie8" for="password">Password</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="password" class="input-block-level" id="password" name="_password" placeholder="Password" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            Remember me
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/profile" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary input-block-level bold higher">
                    SIGN IN
                </button>
            </form>
            <p class="center-align push-down-0">
                <a data-toggle="modal" role="button" href="index-grass-green.html#forgotPassModal" data-dismiss="modal">Forgot your password?</a>
            </p>
       </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <br><br><br>
{% endblock body %}
```

Hope it's all, thanks!

Comment: Did you try to update your `@Route("/login_check", name="security_login_check")` to work with `POST` request ? Because, currently it seems to handle `GET`. use [@Method](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#route-method) annotation and handle POST.

Comment: Synfony does not handle in POST all request if not specified? in the profiler I can see that it's sent in POST . from the profiler: POST Parameters
Key Value
_password ******
_target_path /profile
_username admin

Comment: I would try changing the main-firewall pattern to: `^/` and removing the default-firewall. Also the `loginCheckAction` in your controller is no longer required with symfony 3. Ref: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

Comment: Same behavior, I've removed the default, change main-firewall path and also changed the post login action to {{ path('login') }} so it will post to self. PS: I would like to make the / visible for anonymous user

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's still over-configurated. You don't need an extra firewall for the login (this is probably even the main problem here), so remove `login_firewall`. Using a firewall does not necessarily mean a user needs to login. It just means symfony will try to authenticate access to that *area* of your app. If you absolutely want to use differenty firewalls, then make sure they use the same [`context`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context). For otherwise a successful login to `login_firewall` will account to nothing in `main`.

Comment: Ok, I've just deleted the login_firewall but now I got a redirect loop, can't access login form and any other page, ant suggestion?

Comment: I've tried to paste the form_login with login_path, check_path, username_parameter and password_parameter under  the login firewall and deleted the main firewall so now doesn't cause the loop anymore, but i got the error message "Autentication request can't be processed caused by a system error" and got no POST parameters in profiler

Answer (score 1):

This will not solve andreaems problem, but I ran into the same issue and thought this should be posted here. In my case it was the method

> User::eraseCredentials

setting the password back to null.

```
public function eraseCredentials()
{
    // THIS IS WRONG and led to the error in my case
    // DON'T DO THIS
    $this->password = null
}
```

Hope it helps others.